# Can someone explain why my models hips are doing this after subsurf modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am very new to blender and I decided to make a man. However when I apply a subsurf modifier, my mans hips look strange. Can anyone explain why??

[image]

[image]

Here is a link for my images...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5HB.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some extra geometry in the hip area. Try using Remove Doubles or fixing it manually.

Comment: Just found it. Turns out that the edge was just overlapping a face, instead of creating two. Thanks anyway.